# How to tell squid use Source IP address for sending requests?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, ip, squid

I have two interfaces in my `ifconfig`, eth0 and eth1. Squid is set to accept connections from both of them on port 3000.

However, `eth0`'s ip address is always used to send proxy requests, even if client has connected using `eth1` address.

How do i force squid to *always* use *just* the source IP as **tcp_outgoing_address** (without writing this IP in config file)?

What i've tried additionally:

```
acl from_eth0 src A.B.C.D/1
acl from_eth1 src E.F.G.H/1

tcp_outgoing_address A.B.C.D from_eth0
tcp_outgoing_address E.F.G.H from_eth1
```

If i need to use `iptables`, how exactly rules will look for me?

Comment: I don't think ACLs will work for this - I think you're going to have to do some tinkering with iproute2 - see http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of `acl`. `src` means the client IP and not the interface IP (local address).

I use `localip` acl type for that purpose:

```
acl from_eth0 localip A.B.C.D
acl from_eth1 localip E.F.G.H

tcp_outgoing_address A.B.C.D from_eth0
tcp_outgoing_address E.F.G.H from_eth1
tcp_outgoing_address 1.2.3.4 # default
```

ACL types are described in [doc page](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/).

However, it's painful to write each address by hand. I don't think it's a final solution because of that.